# Multiple group by in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to write a efficient ES query for the below SQL query?

```
Select sum(visits) visits
from index
group by ip, port
order by visits desc
limit 10
```

I am using below ES query, but this will order the visit inside port bucket. I wan't to get top visits after grouping them by destination ip and port.

```
"aggregations" : {
    "ip": 
    {
        "terms": 
        {
            "field": "ip",
            "size": 10
        },
        "aggregations": 
        {
            "port": 
            {
                "terms": 
                {
                    "field": "port",
                    "size": 0,
                    "order": 
                    {
                        "visits": "desc"
                    }
                },
                "aggregations": 
                {
                    "visits": 
                    {
                        "sum": 
                        {
                            "field": "visits"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can some one help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need to have as a result?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Updated my post with answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Data in Elasticsearch**

```
 ip            port           visits

    1.1.1.1        80             10
    1.1.1.2        80             10 
    1.1.1.1        80             20
    1.1.1.3        20             100 
    1.1.1.1        57             20
    1.1.1.1        57             200
```

**ES response**

```
    1.1.1.1        
             57             200
             80             50
    1.1.1.2       
             80             10 
    1.1.1.3        
             20             100
```

**Expected**

```
1.1.1.1        
         57             200
1.1.1.3        
         20             100     
1.1.1.1               
         80             50
1.1.1.2       
         80             10
```

What ES does is, first it group by ip and by port, at last it sum the visit and arrange the visit by desc inside the port aggregator. So This will not give top 10 visits rather it will give top 10 inside each port

**SOLUTION**:

Use script to merge two fields and apply group by

```
 {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "destination": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['ip'].value +  ':'  + doc['port'].value", "order": {
          "visits": "desc"
        }
      },
                "aggregations": 
                {
                    "visits": 
                    {
                        "sum": 
                        {
                            "field": "visits"
                        }

                    }
                }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I think expected values are a little off. E.g. 1.1.1.1 port 57 should be 220, not 200 and 1.1.1.1 port 80 should be 30, not 50. Either that or I'm really confused. Also, could you fix the formatting of the query?